# Where does the money given to the icon of the Ferengi Blessed Exchequer go?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, ferengi

Ferengi use a sort of piggy bank in the image of the [Blessed Exchequer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blessed_Exchequer) to pray and make offerings of latinum.

Where does that money go?

Do the Ferengi send it to some church somewhere or maybe they keep it (making the offering symbolic only)? I have a hard time thinking of Ferengi as charitable in any sense - though a powerful church-estate does seem 'on brand' for them.

Comment: The icon appears to be akin to a piggy bank. It goes to whoever owns the piggy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the EU novel [*Star Trek: SCE - Caveat Emptor*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Caveat_Emptor), diligent Ferengi pay donations to something called "*the Prophets of the Divine Treasury"*, a priestly class who function something like a [chantry order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chantry#Liturgy_for_the_dead), speaking the praises of the donor to their god (for a very reasonable fee). It seems likely that bribes placed in the icon of the Blessed Exchequer would be reserved for this use.

> A matching pair of latinum lobe buffers and fang sharpeners. A
> complete lifetime’s wardrobe of the finest Tholian silk (including
> underwear). An estate in the Colloid marshes. A brand-new, not
> reconditioned, trading schooner with its own captain’s yacht. A moon—
> maybe two.
>
> **Plus, of course, a substantial donation to the Prophets of the Divine
> Treasury— ensuring his name was recited in the Annual Tally so that he
> might be looked upon favorably by the Blessed Exchequer and the
> Celestial Auctioneers.** Forg wasn’t usually so diligent in his
> spiritual devotions, but it never hurt to hedge your bets.

Comment: you've got me wondering now if there aren't criminal Ferengi that raid the transports that carry these donations back to the order akin to how privateers used to pillage Spanish Galleons

Comment: @snerd - Raiding other Ferengi's donations seems like a very easy way to earn the ire of the Blessed Exchequer.

Comment: I take your point but to play devil's advocate, if a Ferengi was able to generate a massive amount of profit this way (like - I can buy my own moon level of profit) would the ends not justify the means in the eyes of the Blessed Exchequer?

Comment: @snerd - In a word, no. Ripping people off is fine, but there are limits to what a Ferengi will do for money. They won't foul their own planet with heavy industry, for example.

Comment: ok. That's a fair and well argued point :)